# How to get value from php javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

I have a file php javascript

in news.js

```
news_id  = 1;
document.write('<div id="news-id"></div>');
function output(strHtml) {
    document.getElementById('news-id').innerHTML = strHtml;
}
```

in news.php is using

```
<?php
    $news_id = 
?>
news_id
<?php
    $str = '<p>This is id: </p>'.$news_id;
?>    
output(<?php echo json_encode($str); ?>);
```

And index.html i call

```
<script src="news.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="news.php" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

When i run `index.html` is error, how to get `news_id` from `js` to using in `php`

Comment: script src="news.**php**" type="text/**javascript**" **facepalm.jpg**

Comment: You cannot pass a JS variable to a PHP file. The PHP is evaluated on the server side, before it ever hits the client (where the JS variable lives).

Comment: @k102 There is nothing wrong with < script src="news.php" type="text/javascript" > as long as news.php returns javascript code.

Comment: @Steve i think you (and maybe those seven people) understood me correctly ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as wrong as the original question is, there is a way to get the a JS variable into a PHP file.

In the HTML:

```
<script src="news.js"></script>
<script>
    document.write('<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript" src="news.php?myvar='+myvar+'" ></scr'+'ipt>');
</script>
```

In news.js:

```
var myvar = "HELLO";
```

In news.php:

```
alert("<?php echo $_GET["myvar"]?>");
```

Again, I highly discourage this approach... but it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call news.php like this. It should be included in the html file like this:

```
include("news.php");
```

and you should change the extension of your html file to .php

Answer (score 0):

To use PHP as javascript source `<script src="news.php"`

you need explicit declare content-type in .php

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/javascript"); //at very first line no white-space before ?>
//this is javascript content..
```

### Important!

first, PHP execute on web server and send response to client(browser).

then javascript execute later in web browser.

To use js value inside php function you need AJAX GET/POST.